# Square of the difference of two four vectors

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, relativity

Given that $p=[\omega(p,m),\, \vec{p}]\,$ is a four vector, where $\omega(p,m)\,=\,\sqrt{\vec{p}^{2}\,+\,m^2}$, and the metric is $g_{\mu\nu}={\text diag}\,(1,-1,-1,-1)$, what is the correct way to evaluate $(p_3-p_4)^2$, where $p_3$ and $p_4$ are four vectors?

Specifically, is the result $$(p_3\,-\,p_4)^2\,=\,(\omega_{p_3}-\omega_{p_4})^{2}\,-\,({\vec p_3}\,-\,{\vec p_4})^{2}?$$

If we go by page 7 of this [note](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-kinematics.pdf), for the Mandelstam variable $t=\,(p_1 -p_3)^2$ as shown, should the evaluation instead be $$(p_3\,-\,p_4)^2\,=\,(\omega_{p_3}+\omega_{p_4})^{2}\,-\,({\vec p_3}\,+\,{\vec p_4})^{2}?$$

Is there a mistake somewhere in my derivation, or these are just different notations, each consistent by itself?

Comment: have made edits to my answer to address the thing you linked.

Comment: The original question has not been answered, as of 1409 hours EST, 11 June.

Comment: Your first result is ok.  Your second result is wrong, as I said in answer.  Can you clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 3):

So we have $p_1=(E_1, \vec{p}_1)$, and $p_2=(E_2, \vec{p}_2)$.

If we consider adding, or subtracting these two 4-vectors, we can just do so component by component.

So $p_{\pm}=(E_1\pm E_2, \vec{p}_1\pm\vec{p}_2)$, where $\pm$ denotes whether we are looking at the sum or the difference of the two vectors.  This is just a standard 4-vector, and so the magnitude of it will simply be $p^2 = (E_1\pm E_2)^2 -(\vec{p}_1\pm\vec{p}_2)^2$.

I'm not sure what has happened with your Mandelstam variable.  You correctly state $t=(p_1-p_3)^2$, but then you write an equation involving $p_3$ and $p_4$.  Your evaluation of $(p_3-p_4)^2$ is also incorrect, c.f. the start of this answer.

**Edit addressing your question**

Another way to do this is to expand $t=(p_1-p_3)^2$, as:
$$(p_1-p_3)^2=(p_1-p_3)(p_1-p_3) = p_1^2 -2p_1\cdot p_3 + p_3^2 $$

The squared terms can straight away be seen as $m_1^2$ and $m_3^2$, and we can calculate the dot product as $p_1\cdot p_3 = E_1 E_3 - \vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{p}_3$.  This all put together gives the result in your link:
$$t=m_1^2 +m_3^2 -2 E_1 E_3 + 2 \vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{p}_3.$$

Comment: $p_1.p_3 = (p_1^0, \vec{p_1}) . (p_3^0, \vec{p_3}) = p_1^0 p_3^0 - \vec{p_1}.\vec{p_3}$

Comment: $(p_1 - p_3)^{2}$ = $(p_1^0 - p_3^0^2$ - $(\vec{p_1}-\vec{p3})^2}$